# @ant-design. Why are all icons added to the bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, antd

I don't understand why all the icons are in the bundle.
Even if I only use the button from "antd"
`import { Button } from 'antd';`

- @ant-design/icons-svg/es/asn - 740kb
- @ant-design/icons/es/icons - 470kb

[webpack-bundle-analyzer.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYoM3.png)

How can this be fixed?

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'import',
      {
        libraryName: 'antd',
        libraryDirectory: 'es',
        style: true,
      },
      'antd',
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Also running into the same issue, having no luck... did you find a workaround?